# Group by year range SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following query. I need MODEL_YEAR_FW 2003 to 2022 to be grouped 3 years each

```
SELECT
COUNT(VEHICLE_FW.MODEL_YEAR_FW) AS COUNT_VEHICLES,
VEHICLES_FW.MODEL_YEAR_FW AS MODEL_YR
FROM
FWUSER.VEHICLES_FW
WHERE
VEHICLES_FW.ARCHIVE_STATUS_FW - 'N'
AND ( (MODEL_YEAR_FW) >2003)
GROUP BY
VEHICLE_FW.MODEL_YEAR_FW
ORDER BY
VEHICLES_FW.MODEL_YEAR_FW
```

Someone please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `DENSE_RANK()` analytic function as the following:

```
WITH RANKS AS
(
  SELECT MODEL_YEAR_FW, ARCHIVE_STATUS_FW,
         CEILING(DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MODEL_YEAR_FW)/3) GRP
  FROM VEHICLES_FW
  WHERE ARCHIVE_STATUS_FW = 'N'AND MODEL_YEAR_FW >2003
)
SELECT CONCAT(MIN(MODEL_YEAR_FW), '-', MAX(MODEL_YEAR_FW)) AS MODEL_YR,
       COUNT(MODEL_YEAR_FW) AS COUNT_VEHICLES
FROM RANKS
GROUP BY GRP
ORDER BY GRP
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/6-gunlBY).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the modulo operator `%`

```
SELECT VEHICLE_FW.MODEL_YEAR_FW % 3 AS interval3y, 
       count(*) AS COUNT_VEHICLES,
       min(VEHICLES_FW.MODEL_YEAR_FW) AS MODEL_YR
FROM FWUSER.VEHICLES_FW
WHERE VEHICLES_FW.ARCHIVE_STATUS_FW = 'N'
  AND MODEL_YEAR_FW >= 2003
GROUP BY interval3y
ORDER BY interval3y
```